# SQL Query to retrieve list of a field between two dates

Tags: java, mysql

I have a table in which there are two columns namely startTime and endTime (both are DateTime dataTypes) there is another column 'Duration' which calculates the difference between these two. I want to retrieve Duration between specific dates like June10-June20. The problem is I've many rows for same date and Few dates between the range dont even exist. I need to plot the graph for the specified range. So, I have to append zero to the output when there is no entry for a particular day and the similar day's value has to be added together and returned as a single value. So, the output rows should be equal to the number of days specified.
[Click here for Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXvMQ.png)
Thanx in advance.

Comment: add the example to your question, people probably won't click on a link to get more information

Comment: Thank you for your response. There was a problem with indentation and hence I chose this option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the start and end dates in every row would differ only in the time component. 
Also assuming that you do not have any other table that has dates listed and you need a dynamic table to list all the dates between the given range.
You could do the following.

```
select list_of_dates.date, ifnull(sum(your_table.duration),0) 
from your_table 
right join 
(SELECT DATE(ADDDATE('2016-06-20', INTERVAL @i:=@i+1 DAY)) AS date 
FROM your_table, 
(select @i:=-1) local
HAVING 
@i < DATEDIFF('2016-06-25', '2016-06-20') ) list_of_dates 
on list_of_dates.date = date(your_table.start_date)  
group by list_of_dates.date
```

If you have a table that stores relevant calendar it gets easier

```
select calendar_table.date, ifnull(sum(your_table.duration),0) 
from your_table 
right join 
calendar_table 
on calendar_table.date = date(your_table.start_date)
where calendar_table.date >= '2016-06-20' and calendar_table.date <= '2016-06-25'
group by calendar_table.date
```